# Return cv::Mat* variable does not work as expected

Tags: c++, opencv

When returning a OpenCV cv::Mat* variable (correctly initialized) it seems like it looses all of its content. What am I doing wrong?

```
// @called function
template<mxClassID CID>
cv::Mat* helper_2dmat_to_mat_ptr(const mxArray* mat) {
    int M = mxGetM(mat), N = mxGetN(mat);
    const int TYPE = mcv_traits<CID>::CV_TYPE;
    cv::Mat pOutMat;
    pOutMat.create(M, N, TYPE);
    cv::Mat* pOutMat_ptr = &pOutMat;

    void* pBegOut = static_cast<void*>(pOutMat_ptr->data);
    int pitch = pOutMat_ptr->step;

    typedef typename mc_traits<CID>::CT T;
    void* pBeg = mxGetData(mat);
    pix_iterator_2d<T, eColWise> it_src1(
    static_cast<T*>(pBeg), N, M);
    pix_iterator_2d<T, eColWise> it_src2(
    static_cast<T*>(pBeg), N, M);
    it_src2.end();
    pix_iterator_2d<T, eRowWise> it_dest(
    static_cast<T*>(pBegOut), N, M, pitch);

    std::copy(it_src1, it_src2, it_dest);

    /**
     * If I check the content of 'pOutMat' here, it correctly
     * contains the matrix it is supposed to contain (i.e. a [3x3] matrix
     * with numbers from 1 to 9)
     */
    return pOutMat_ptr;
}

// @caller function
cv::Mat* mxArr_to_new_Mat_ptr(const mxArray* mat) {
    const mxClassID id = mxGetClassID(mat);
    mwSize const ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mat);
    if (2 == ndim) {
        if (mxDOUBLE_CLASS == id) {
            cv:: Mat* out = helper_2dmat_to_mat_ptr<mxDOUBLE_CLASS>(mat);
            /**
             * If I check the content of 'out' here it seems empty
             */
        }
        else if (...)
    }
    ... other irrelevant code ...
}
```

My question is simple: why before the 'return' command the pointer points to a non-empty matrix whereas when the control goes back to the caller function this data seems disapperared?

My guess would be that it has to do with the fact that the inner function (helper_2dmat_to_mat_ptr) has a scope which cannot be seen from the outer function (mxArr_to_new_Mat_ptr), but how can I solve the problem? What is more, as you can see, the outer function (mxArr_to_new_Mat_ptr) is supposed to do some operation on the cv::Mat* before doing basically the same thing as the inner function.

Comment: 1) Using pointers to `Mat` is in general a bad idea. `Mat` is already a "smart pointer" to the underlying data. 2) You need to use `clone()` somewhere... but you should show all your code ([mcve])

Comment: Yes you are right. The main structure of this code was not written by me, and I am just trying to adapt it to the use of cv::Mat instead of CvMat variable.I just edited the question to add all the code of the inner function.

Comment: `cv::Mat* pOutMat_ptr = &pOutMat;` What happens when `pOutMat` goes out of scope? ;)

Comment: well it is evident that it is destroyed, but how can I avoid this problem? there is no way but passing pOutMat from the outside and returning it? I mean like in:
cv::Mat* helper_2dmat_to_mat_ptr(const mxArray* mat, cv::Mat pOutMat)

Comment: `cv::Mat* pOutMat_ptr = new Mat(...)`

Comment: @Miki I just tried doing as you suggested in the beginning, i.e. avoiding completely the use of Mat* and it seems to work fine. Thanks for the suggestion! As soon as I am sure it works flawlessly I will post an answer explaining how I did it. Still, I did not understand why you suggested to use 'new Mat'